# NAudio decode stream of bytes

Tags: naudio

Hi
I am using the NAudio library at http://naudio.codeplex.com/

I have this hardware made by some manufacturer which claims to send
audio with the following characteristics.

aLaw 8khz, AUD:11,0,3336,0

Not sure what it all  means at this stage.

I received bunch of bytes from this device when a user speaks into the
equipment.
Hence I am constantly recieving a stream of bytes at particular times

At this stage I have been unable to decode the audio so I can hear
what is spoken into the device with my headphones.

I have tried writing the audio to a file doing code like

FWaveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter("C:\Test4.wav",
WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1));

And have been unable to playback the sound using the sample demo apps.

I have tried similar code from

http://naudio.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=231245 and
http://naudio.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=83270

and still have not been able to achieve much.

Any information is appreciated.
Thanks
Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are definitely receiving raw a-law audio (mono 8kHz) then your code to create a WAV file should work correctly and result in a file that can play in Windows Media Player.

I suspect that maybe your incoming byte stream is wrapped in some other kind of protocol. I'm afraid I don't know what "AUD:11,0,3336,0" means, but that might be a place to start investigating. Do you hear anything intelligible at all when you play back the file?

Comment: Hi, I use the LumiSOft.dll to decode the aLaw/ULaw bytes and using the
WaveOut class, I have been able to hear the stream of bytes on my headphones.
Code is at
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Streaming_wave_audio.aspx
Thanks anyway